# why is this compile error in Java varargs (int ...x,double ...y)?

Tags: java, methods, variadic-functions

```
static void m(int ...x,double ...y){}
```

I'm try to use this method. But it compile error.I want to know the reason.

```
int x[]=new int[2];
double y[]=new double[2];
```

I make two arrays like this and i want parse them to method **m**.

```
m(x,y); like this.
```

Comment: You can only have one varargs parameter in method and it needs to be at the end.

Comment: Where do the `int`s and the `double`s start? `varargs` can only be used as the last parameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not have double varargs but the key question is "why this is not possible?" because the restriction does not come from Java itself. For example consider this two cases:

1. If you have `someMehod(Shape ...shape, Square ...square)` -> you don't know where the `Shape` args stop or where `Square` args begin.
2. If `Square` extends `Shape`-> the `Shape` class can exist in `...shape` and `...square` args due the polymorphism and this is quite confusing.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot have double varargs like `void m(int ...x,double ...y){}`.

Instead you can have `void m(int[] x, double[] y){}`.

Answer (score 4):

Reading from official documentation:

> Varargs can be used only in the final argument position.

[Oracle documentation on Varargs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/language/varargs.html)